# Phoenix error internationalization

Tags: internationalization, elixir, gettext, phoenix-framework

I am translating my application through *.po-files, but the command

```
mix gettext.extract --merge
```

generates options only for hardcoded strings.
I have read in documentation that I can't edit *.po-files manually because they are overwritten every time.
How can I translate errors that come from changeset validations and so on?

Answer (score 0):

`dgettext`for errors is called in `web/views/error_helpers.ex`

I'm not sure if these get extracted and merged into `errors.po`, but that's where you'd likely put them manually if they do not.